# 3rd-party Knowledge-focused prestige class that can read books quickly

Tags: dnd-3.5e, product-identification, dnd-3e

I remember having had read the description of a prestige class D&D 3.0 or 3.5 supplemental book. If I remember correctly, it was none of the official WOTC sources. I think it was a book in black and white only print.

The class was about worshiping a deity with a knowledge focus (probably knowledge domain in the possibly alternate, non-official setting). Having that deity as a patron was a requirement to enter the prestige class.

The character class had a class feature that allowed it to **read a whole book in a round** (probably as a full round action).

Does anyone know the publication or the name of the referenced prestige class?

(I think there is a bard spell (as KRyan pointed out called *scholar's touch*) that enables the target to do something similar - knowing the basic details of a touched book within a round. That's not what I am looking for)

Comment: For the record, the spell you remember is *scholar’s touch*, a 1st-level bard, cleric, sor/wiz spell from _Races of Destiny_, which allows you to read one touched book per round for up to caster level rounds. A 1st-level human cleric with the Undeath and Planning domains and the Persistent Spell and Divine Metamagic feats (and at least 10 Charisma) could maintain that all day, every day, for what it’s worth. Obviously, you may have other reasons to look for this class, so not at all an answer here, but thought it might be relevant to your interests.

Comment: @KRyan Thank you for the hint! I was not able to find scholar's touch at time of posting.
Yes, IIRC the wording of the prestige classes feature is less restrictive in the sense that more than "This [the retained information] is equivalent to a solid reading but not deep study - 
the character does not gain perfect recall of the information, just whatever he would have gotten from reading it completely once" (wording of the scholar's touch spell) level of knowledge/detail is retained via the prestige class feature.